# How to include a custom component in form?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

I have a component named "Employee-type" (which includes a select component) which will be used for showing corresponding employees list(datagrid).
How do I re-use the same component inside a form as shown below with extra features like valid, invalid, dirty, touched etc.?

[image]

Comment: What is the code of your component looking like?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple reusable select component, using @angular/material mat-select. Checkout out the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wufe6x).

my-select.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  template: `
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="ctrl" [placeholder]="placeholder">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  `,
  styles: [`:host { display: block; }`]
})
export class MySelectComponent  {
  @Input() ctrl: FormControl;
  @Input() options: string[];
  @Input() placeholder: string;
}
```

Example usage:

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <my-select [ctrl]="form.get('cities')" [options]="cities" placeholder="Cities"></my-select>
    <my-select [ctrl]="form.get('countries')" [options]="countries" placeholder="Countries"></my-select>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  cities = ['Krakow', 'Warszawa', 'Gdansk'];
  countries = ['Poland', 'Germany', 'Sweden'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      cities: ['', Validators.required],
      countries: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a `formControlName` on `<my-select>`, so that I can get the selected value (in this case the selected city) from `my-select` to the parent component? (I have a radio button group component and I need the selected radio's value out).

Comment: I just came across an article on how to use `formControlName` at https://medium.com/@paynoattn/custom-angular2-form-components-using-formbuilder-bb9068cd4057